# Snowflake create intergration not having privileges on trail account

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I got an Snowflake trail account on Azure. I am trying to create snowpipe to auto ingest files from Azure Blob storage to Snowflake tables. In order do this one of the step is to Create Notification Integration command but my snowflake trail account doesn't have sufficient privilege to execute this command even with Accountadmin role.

SQL access control error: Insufficient privileges to operate on account 'XYZ'

Is this limitation on Snowflake trail account or any other privileges missing ? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

In Snowflake you need the role ACOUNTADMIN or a role with
the CREATE INTEGRATION privilege to run the CREATE NOTIFICATION INTEGRATION command: https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/create-notification-integration.html

Probably you accidentaly chose the wrong role?

Note: The role in the top right corner may differ from the role set in your worksheet. The role in the worksheet is used - probably here is the error?

Comment: You can put and run this SQL right before your CREATE INTEGRATION command:
USE ROLE ACCOUNTADMIN;

Comment: Exactly. This will update the role on the worksheet level I mentioned.